# PropTypes undefined in react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm building a react native application which navigates through drawer menu.So i installed react navigation  and tried to import the createDrwaerNavigator from the library but soon as i import im getting the following error.I don't understand the reason.Any help on this is highly appreciated.

```
import {createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation'; //error comes from here
```

[image: erro]

The following are the versions used :-

```
"react-navigation": "^3.6.0",
"react-native": "0.59.10",
"prop-types": "^15.7.2",
```

Comment: Can you show the content of `createMaterialTopTabNavigator.js`?

Comment: @Remeus that's the react navigation library class any way i will update the question with the class.

Comment: Oh yeah true, read too fast. Just give us the content of the file where you define the drawer.

Comment: You can find the code here basically same code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57196595/dispatch-a-function-call-from-custom-drawer-menu-to-screen-in-react-navigation)

Comment: you most use prop type like this : size: PropTypes.number. did you check it?

Comment: @Moein thanks for your suggestion but the error comes from library(react-navigation) but the same library (navigation) and code is working when i built so i don't think that will solve my issue

Comment: @Archulan that was my typing mistake here :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating react-navigation? (latest version is 3.11.0)

The PropTypes module has been externalized to anotther module, and is not part of react anymore, maybe your are importing it the old way?

Showing your code could help, as we do not have much information here :/

Comment: thanks for your suggestion yes updated to the latest version ("react-navigation": "^3.11.1") still throwing error for you info i'm just installing and importing the module and it's throwing the error so i don't think you require code for it but the same import code is working in ios.